# Pass array of arrays from javascript to spring mvc controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, spring-mvc

So I have a little issue here as described. In the following first example I'm passing a simple array which is working. If I want to pass a array of arrays in the second example, it isn't working anymore. Any suggestions?

this works:

**JS**

```
var myArrayOfStrings = ["x", "y"];

function createConsumer(){
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/save",
             data: { myArray: myArrayOfStrings }
        });
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    void Submit(@RequestParam("myArray[]") String[] name) {
        System.out.println(name[0]);
    }
```

The following solution isn't working, why? I just want to pass an *Array of Array* instead of a "simple Array".  How will it work?

**JS**

```
var myArrayOfArrays = [["x", "y"],["x", "y"]];


function createConsumer(){
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/save",
             data: { myArray: myArrayOfArrays }
        });
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    void Submit(@RequestParam("myArray[][]") String[][] name) {
        System.out.println(name[0][0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution worked

**JS**

```
var myArrayOfArrays = [["x", "y"],["x", "y"]];

function createConsumer(){
    $.ajax({
         contentType: "application/json",
         type: "POST",
         url: "/save",
         data: JSON.stringify(myArrayOfArrays)
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void Submit(@RequestBody String[][] name) {
        System.out.println(name[0][0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should serialize your nested array with JSON.stringify() before you pass it with AJAX.

```
var myArrayOfArrays = [["x", "y"],["x", "y"]];

function createConsumer(){
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/save",
         data: JSON.stringify({ myArray: myArrayOfArrays })
    });
}
```

Kind regards.

Comment: How would I change the controller?

Comment: @RequestParam("myArray") String name